# ARDUİNO DUE measurement nanoseconds time

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

For my project I need to measure time in nanosecond fineness. (Like measuring the travel time of radio waves in air).

Hello,
I'm new to Arduino due.
If I go into a little detail, I have boards such as Raspberry Pi 3 B+, Arduino DUE, Esp32.
In the tests I made at home, DUE gave an accuracy of +- 1 us and a stable time measurement. However, in field tests, the arduino due measures the travel time of radio waves to 0 when 600 meters away from the transmitting station. I measure time with simple micros command.
For this reason, I started looking for more sensitive ways to measure time. And I need to know how to measure in nanosecond precision. The accuracy I'm looking for is 0.5 us or more, like 200 nanoseconds.
I'm waiting for your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the clock rate of the board you use. A 16MHz clock will let the *hardware* quantize pulse widths of 0.0625us. Read their datasheets and find out what their timers can do for you. You don't want to measure this in software. The $4USB Raspberry Pi Pico has a 125MHz clock, and could get you 8ns resolution.

Comment: Well, I wonder how I can do this in arduino due. I'm very new so I need help.